# Print bit rate and signal level in one row

Tags: iwconfig

I want to print out the bit rate and signal level of iwconfig in one row and separate with space. So far I use different command to print the bit rate and signal strength separately like this :

> iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Bit Rate/ {print $4}'
>
> iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}'

and the result will be

> 54
>
> -43

Is it possible to make them like this :

> 54 -43

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
One simple way is to assign the output of your commands
to variables.  That way, you can print them out however you want.
I just tested this on Ubuntu 12.4.  Note the back quotes around
the commands.

v1=`iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Bit Rate/ {print $4}'`

v2=`iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}'`

echo $v1 $v2
```